# Equivalent for ResourceFilterFactory in jersey 2

Tags: java, jersey

I have a Filter factory class to be made with two factory classes and a cache implementation . How to implement the equivalent implementation for ResourceFilterFactory in Jersey 2 ?

My Class definition is

```
public class CORSResourceFilterFactory implements ResourceFilterFactory {
```

I have a create method that implements cache functionality based on whether the Method type is Options or not .

```
 public List<ResourceFilter> create(AbstractMethod am) {

   //Getting the Origin , Methods , Headers and Credentials

        if (am.isAnnotationPresent(OPTIONS.class)) {
            filters = Collections.<ResourceFilter>singletonList(new CORSOptionsFilter(o, m, h, c));
        } else {
            filters = Collections.<ResourceFilter>singletonList(new CORSSimpleFilter(o, h, c));
        }

        filterCache.put(am, filters);
        return filters;
    }
}
```

The individual filter constructor definition are as follows :

```
 public CORSOptionsFilter(Collection<String> o, Collection<String> m,
            Collection<String> h, boolean c) {
            }
public CORSSimpleFilter(Collection<String> o,
            Collection<String> h, boolean c) {
    }
```